# Comparing diagnostic accuracy of diagnostic tests with lme4

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I compare two diagnostic tests. Therfore, I collected patient data from several studies. The dataframe is similar to this one:

```
set.seed(10)
data = data.frame( test1 = rbinom(1000, 1, 0.6),
               test2 = rbinom(1000, 1, 0.4),
               reference = rbinom(1000, 1, 0.7),   
               study = sort(paste("study_", round(runif(1000, 1, 20),0) ,sep = "")),
               id = 1:1000,
               age = round(rnorm(1000, 60, 10), 0))
```

I did a lot of research on how to use hierarchical models for calculating the respective sensitivities and specifities for my tests and tried a lot of variations in the formula of `glmer`. However, I don't have sufficient  statistical knowledge for interpreting these models. So I don't know if my approach is correct. Therfore I am showing you my latest model.

First, I would like to calculate the logit sensitivity and specifity for each test. 
In a paper by [Genders et al.](http://pubs.rsna.org/doi/suppl/10.1148/radiol.12120509) [(appendices)](http://pubs.rsna.org/doi/suppl/10.1148/radiol.12120509/suppl_file/12120509appendices.pdf) a Stata code to calculate the logit sensitivity and specifity is provided.
I transferred this code to "R", but I am not sure if it's correct this way.

```
m.sen <- glmer(test1 ~ ( 1 | study) + ( 1 | id ), data = subset(data, reference == 1), 
               family = binomial(link = "logit"), control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"), nAGQ = 1)

require("useful")
m.spe <-  glmer(binary.flip(test1) ~ ( 1 | study) + ( 1 | id ), data = subset(data, reference == 0), 
                family = binomial(link = "logit"), control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"), nAGQ = 1)

logit.sen = fixef(m.sen)  #  0.4079496 
logit.spe = fixef(m.spe)  #  -0.5845133
```

My first question is if it is possible to calculate the logit sensitivity and specifity of a diagnostic test like this.
The next step would be to adjust for different patient characteristics, such as age.

```
data <- within(data, {age = as.factor(round(age, -1))})
m.sen.age <- glmer(test1 ~ age + ( 1 | study) + ( 1 | id ), data = subset(data, reference == 1),
                   family = binomial(link = "logit"), control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"), nAGQ = 1)
fix <- fixef(m.sen.age)

# (Intercept)          age30          age40          age50          age60          age70          age80 
#  14.5660762259 -13.4674641465 -14.0319936288 -14.5514773535 -14.1892664080 -14.0713799056 -13.2897828741 
#  age90         age100 
#  -14.1606112199   0.0001916363
```

Now I add the estimates. For example, to determine the logit sensitivity of test1 in patients aged between 55 and 65: `sen.50 = fix[1] + fix[5] # 0.3768098` 
As an alternative, I thought about further defining the data subset, which produces nearly identically results:

```
m.sen.age <- glmer(test1 ~ ( 1 | study) + ( 1 | id ), data = subset(data, reference == 1 & age == 60), 
                   family = binomial(link = "logit"), control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"), nAGQ = 1)
sen.age50 = fixef(m.sen.age) # 0.3768099
```

Comment: I have been scouring an RCode to do the same but haven't been able to find one apart from the one presented here. Did you ever find out whether this was the right approach? Thanks B